# Own SuperGlobal Variable in PHP?

Tags: php, apache, variables, global

I was reading something about SuplerGlobals like $_SERVER or (see more detail [PHP Manual Superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)) the other day, now, I'm asking me:

Is it possible to implement own SuperGlobals? 
Beside of Constants...

So for example user A writes something in the Variable which, if User B is calling it can see.
Something like a server wide Session Variable or something.

Please don't be to hard, if its a silly question :)
I know there are couple of ways outside, like SQL, Xml and Stuff, but maybe...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP doesn't have context which can be shared between users. You should some replacement like SQL server or file. You may also check some extensions like [memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) which might help you achieve your goal.

Comment: Its a german page, but seems exactly to be what i was looking for:[link](http://www.web-skripte.de/script_memcache.htm) Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your whole idea of PHP superglobals it wrong.
These variables are always available in terms of just one script runtime, no the whole site.

Answer (score 2):

> I was reading something about SuplerGlobals like $_SERVER or (see more detail PHP Manual Superglobals) the other day, now, I'm asking me:
>
> Is it possible to implement own SuperGlobals? Beside of Constants...

Yes it is possible if you've got the [PHP runkit](http://php.net/manual/en/runkit.configuration.php) extension.

> So for example user A writes something in the Variable which, if User B is calling it can see

That's not what superglobals do - they are variables which exist in global scope (i.e. for the duration of an instance of a script).

If you want to share data between different invocations then you need to send it to your storage tier or (in the case of data for a single client) out to the browser.

Since what you are describing here is effectively a shared session, then the sensible place to implement this would be in the session handler.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, you can only see your own session data.

To achieve this you would need to store the data somewhere else. in text files or in a MySQL database would be the most common.

Comment: using files is hard to scale (and probably not fast) and a Database - ok, I know them, but that wasn't what i was looking for :) Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose you can use `(asterix)export yourvar="something"(asterix)` and to receive it using getenv

sry, dont know how to embed asterix=`, but it is better to avoid it...

If you use apache following could be used:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-setenv.php

same idea, enveroinment variable

Comment: env variables won't work either. it will be set for the local context only

Comment: You are wrong. If PHP is run from console - it WILL be shared. Using setenv in wont be shared, using call with asterix to export it will be shared. If php run thru apache it will be shared with http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-setenv.php, you better read manual before making such statements

Comment: Hmm. With quick test I was unable to get the value in the separate request. Are you sure it works this way?

Comment: yes, the code to set is `apache_setenv('foo','bar',1);` and to get is `echo apache_getenv('foo');`